# Error while trying to combine two arrays in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I use this function to combine results of two arrays of equal length

for eg: if am combining two arrays say, `Array A` and `Array B`

output would be of the format `array[Value of Array A]=value of Array B`

```
combined = fields.reduce(function(obj, val, i) {
    obj[val] = edit_opt[i];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

This function does what i want when tested in chrome and firefox, but however when i tested my code in IE 8,9 i get an error.
I've posted the message below.

Webpage error details

> ```
> > User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2;
> > Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
> > 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729) Timestamp: Sat, 21 Jul 2012 10:29:23 UTC
>
>
> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
> Line: 94
> Char: 5
> Code: 0
> URI: http://x.x.x.x/grid_test/
>
> note: line 94 is the beginning of my combine function.
> ```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: try to add "var combined = ..." instead of "combined = ..."

Comment: The `reduce` function is also not supported in IE 8. So you can leave that out.

Comment: Wasn't implemented. Try running `[].reduce` in those browsers and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> **Array.prototype.reduce** is an ECMAScript 5 addition; as such it may not be present in other implementations of the standard.

You *can work around* this by inserting the following code at the beginning of your scripts, allowing use of reduce in implementations which do not natively support it.

```
if (!Array.prototype.reduce) {  
        Array.prototype.reduce = function reduce(accumulator){  
        if (this===null || this===undefined) throw new TypeError("Object is null or undefined");  
        var i = 0, l = this.length >> 0, curr;  

        if(typeof accumulator !== "function") // ES5 : "If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception."  
          throw new TypeError("First argument is not callable");  

        if(arguments.length < 2) {  
          if (l === 0) throw new TypeError("Array length is 0 and no second argument");  
          curr = this[0];  
          i = 1; // start accumulating at the second element  
        }  
        else  
          curr = arguments[1];  

        while (i < l) {  
          if(i in this) curr = accumulator.call(undefined, curr, this[i], i, this);  
          ++i;  
        }  

        return curr;  
      };    
 }
```

<sub>[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Compatibility)</sub>

Comment: @ Engineer worked perfectly for me, a ton of thanks to you mate i have been breaking my head over this all morning and thank you andreas, davin and amberlamps for lending a hand.